# How to close ExcelPackage using EPPlus in C#?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

I'm using epplus to write in a file an extense quantity of information in an excel template, but then I need to close the ExcelPackage as to be usable with the Excel application. It throws me this exception: "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC"

```
    private void FillCardsSheet()
    {
        xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(Template);

        wsCards = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[4];

        string command = "SELECT * FROM dbo_serial_cards WHERE type <> 'EXT' AND LEFT([device_tag], 2) <> '!!'";
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, CON);
        OleDbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        int row = 1;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            row++;
            for (int col = 1; col <= 16; col++)
            {
                wsCards.Cells[row, col].Value = reader.GetValue(col - 1);
            }
        }

        xlPackage.SaveAs(Template);
        xlPackage.Dispose();
    }
```

Comment: Where are you getting the exception? What line? EPPlus doesn't use COM at all.

Comment: 0x800A03EC = ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS. I assume this is from the OleDb stuff - EEPlus won't be automating Excel will it?

Answer (score 2):

Hard to say without more details about your connection and objects.  What is 'Template'?  Might help if you say which line is generating the error (like @mason mentioned). That is a COM error you seem to be getting so it could be with the db connection or maybe the package itself.  Since the package is being managed outside the method make sure it is not locked or closed.

This worked fine for me connection to a local SQL Server db:

```
[TestMethod]
public void SQL_Reader_Test()
{
    var Template = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\temp.xlsx");
    if (Template.Exists)
        Template.Delete();

    var xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(Template);

    //var wsCards = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets[4];
    var wsCards = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Cards");

    //const string constring = @"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\temp\northwind.mdb;Persist Security Info=False;";
    const string constring = @"Provider=SQLNCLI11;Data Source=MYMACHINENAME\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;UID=AdventureWorks; Pwd=AdventureWorks";

    using (var CON = new OleDbConnection(constring))
    {
        CON.Open();

        //string command = "SELECT * FROM dbo_serial_cards WHERE type <> 'EXT' AND LEFT([device_tag], 2) <> '!!'";
        const string command = "SELECT * FROM Person.Address";
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand(command, CON);
        var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        int row = 1;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            row++;
            //for (int col = 1; col <= 16; col++)
            for (int col = 1; col <= reader.FieldCount; col++)
            {
                wsCards.Cells[row, col].Value = reader.GetValue(col - 1);
            }
        }

        xlPackage.SaveAs(Template);
        xlPackage.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: Template is a FileInfo with the path of the excel template that i'm using

Comment: Which exact line is causing the error in your code?

Comment: xlPackage.SaveAs(Template);

Comment: Ok, so it is definitely an excel/com problem.  What if you create a brand new excel file and sheet like I did above, does the problem go away.  The Template file - is that a true XLSX and not an XLS or XLTX?

Comment: its a xlsm because later on I need to run a macro to create a .fhx

Comment: That should still work.  What happens if you comment all lines above saveas except 'xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(Template);'?  Does it still give the error?  I would guess the problem lies with the file itself.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the ExcelPackage within an Using-Block:

```
using (ExcelPackage xlsPackage = new ExcelPackage(Template))
{
    // Your Code
    xlPackage.SaveAs(Template);
}
```

Comment: None of the [EPPlus examples](http://epplus.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=WebapplicationExample) have a `using` block or call `Dispose()`. I'm guessing it's not necessary, since it's purely in managed code and doesn't use any external resources.

Comment: EPPlus doesn't use COM. The OP is disposing the package anyway.

Comment: A using-block is essentially the same as calling Dispose().

Comment: @mason Well, all examples i have from EPPlus have a using-Block, even that which you refer to ;)